# How can i add two word dataframes Rstudio

Tags: r

So i have two dataframes:

First:

[image]

Second:

[image]

By using  `documentSolr <- rbind(firstDataframe,secondDataframe)` i achieved:

```
          word freq
zobacz  zobacz    1
zobacz1 zobacz    1
etc.
```

[image]

But the "zobacz" word is duplicated. How can i add this two dataframes to achive something like this:

```
         word freq
zobacz zobacz    2
zdjęć  zdjęć     1
etc.
```

I tried merging, joins but without success...

Comment: Using dplyr: `documentSolr %>% group_by(word) %>% summarize(freq = sum(freq))`

Comment: I was fighting with this for two hours... Thank you Phill.

Answer (score 0):

A base R approach:

```
df1
#  names data
#1   hhh    1
#2   hhh    1
#3   hhf    1
#4  hhd1    1
#5   hhr    1
#6   hhw    1
#7   ffs    1

df2
#  names data
#1   hhh    1
#2   hhh    1
#3   hhf    1
#4  hhd1    1
#5   hhr    1
#6   hhw    1
#7   fft    1

dfa <- rbind( df1, df2 )

setNames( data.frame(sapply( unique(dfa$names),
  function(x) sum( dfa$data[dfa$names == x]) )), c("data") )
#     data
#hhh     4
#hhf     2
#hhd1    2
#hhr     2
#hhw     2
#ffs     1
#fft     1
```